# Google-apps-script: Unique ID's in extensible rows

Tags: google-apps-script

I've a column with 40 different numbers, listed from 1.. to 40.
When I insert a row above or below an other row the number of this new row should be 41, ignoring the sequence.
None of the numbers should occur twice or be deleted.

The idea is that there are unique ID's for each row and that the number of rows can grow.

How would a function for this idea look in google-script for a google-spreadsheet?

I tried it with script-cell-functions and normal given functions but unfortunately I'm stuck.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script below does strictly what you ask for. That means also that it works only if  newly inserted row cell is empty. (it can fill multiple inserted rows thanks to ++maxval in the second loop). It won't work if you add an empty row after the last one (in fact the ID cell must be empty but there must be something in this row so that the script 'sees' it) but that's quite logical !

```
function fillRowNumber(){
  var col = 1 ; // this for column A ! change to your needs
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataincol = sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getMaxRows(),1).getValues();
  var maxval =0
  for(n=0;n<dataincol.length;++n){
    if(Number(dataincol[n][0])>maxval){ maxval=Number(dataincol[n][0])}
    }
  for(n=1;n<sh.getLastRow();++n){
    if(dataincol[n-1][0] == ''){ dataincol[n-1][0]=maxval+1;++maxval}
    }
  sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getMaxRows(),1).setValues(dataincol);
}
```